# How do I generate a table of contents for HTML text in Python?

Tags: python, html, tableofcontents

Assume that I have some HTML code, like this (generated from Markdown or Textile or something):

```
<h1>A header</h1>
<p>Foo</p>
<h2>Another header</h2>
<p>More content</p>
<h2>Different header</h2>
<h1>Another toplevel header
<!-- and so on -->
```

How could I generate a table of contents for it using Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an HTML parser such as [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to find all header elements.

Comment: @van: BeautifulSoup is pure Python but not very 3.x-compatible. lxml is good, but requires a C compiler to build.

Comment: I was really looking more for some example code, but I think I have figured it out. I'll probably use lxml, since (a) it's useful for more stuff, and (b) having a module that looks like a class name disturbs my sense of aesthetics.

Comment: I'm not sure about 2010, but these days beautifulsoup can use lxml as parser so you can have the best of both words (speed and convenience).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using lxml and xpath.

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse("test.xml")
for node in doc.xpath('//h1|//h2|//h3|//h4|//h5'):
    print node.tag, node.text
```